# Creating a method calledcalcWinPercentage(). we have to make sure we do not divide by 0 . If there have been no games played, return -1

Tags: java, methods, percentage

Modify  displayPlayer() to  also    display winning percentage.     Since   winning
percentage is   a   calculated  value,  it  is  not stored  in  the object  (and    there   is  no  data
field).     Instead of  displaying  a   field,  the method  calcWinPercentage() will    be  called.
The value   returned    by  the method  will    be  multiplied  by  100 for whole   number  form.
Display this    value   to  one digit   after   the decimal point.      To  display the percent sign
with    printf, use %%.     If  no  games   have    been    played, -1  will    be  returned    from
calcWinPercentage, and  you should display  “No games   played” for winning
percentage.

I am a begginner level java user. Not sure why I am getting a NAN error or -100 as my percentage.

```js
public class TestTennisPlayer2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ShresthaTennisPlayer tp1 = new  ShresthaTennisPlayer();
    ShresthaTennisPlayer tp2 = new  ShresthaTennisPlayer("Serena", "Williams", "USA");
    ShresthaTennisPlayer tp3 = new  ShresthaTennisPlayer("Simona", "Halep", "Romania", 4, 27);
    ShresthaTennisPlayer tp4 = new  ShresthaTennisPlayer("Sloane", "Stephens", "USA", 8, 26, 18, 11);
    
    tp1.displayPlayer();
    tp2.displayPlayer();
    tp3.displayPlayer();
    tp4.displayPlayer();
    
    
   
    
  }
}
```

```css
public class ShresthaTennisPlayer
{
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  
  private String country;
  
  private int rank;
  private int age;
  
  private int wins;
  private int losses;
  
  double winningPercentage;
  double totalGames;
  
  double winPercentage = calcWinPercentage();
  
  public ShresthaTennisPlayer()
  { 
      firstName = null;
      lastName = null;
      country = null;
      
      rank = 0;
      age = 0;
      wins = 0;
      losses = 0; 
  }
  
  public ShresthaTennisPlayer(String FName, String LName, String CountryName)
  {
  firstName = FName;
  lastName = LName;
  country = CountryName;
  
  rank = 0;
  age = 0;
  wins = 0;
  losses = 0;
  }
  
  
  public ShresthaTennisPlayer(String FName, String LName, String CountryName, int r, int a)
  {
  firstName = FName;
  lastName = LName;
  country = CountryName;
  
  rank = r;
  age = a;
  wins = 0;
  losses = 0;
  }
  
  public ShresthaTennisPlayer(String FName, String LName, String CountryName, int r, int a, int w, int l)
  {
  firstName = FName;
  lastName = LName;
  country = CountryName;
  
  rank = r;
  age = a;
  wins = w;
  losses = l;
  }
  public void setFirstName(String FName)
  {
    firstName = FName;
  }
  
  public void setLastName(String LName)
  {
lastName = LName;
  }
  
  public void setCountry(String CountryName)
  {
    country = CountryName;
  }
  
  public void setRank(int r)
  {
    rank = r;
  }
  
  public void setAge(int a)
  {
age = a;
  }
  
  public void setWins(int w)
  {
    wins = w;
  }
  
  public void setLosses(int l)
  {
    losses = l;
  }
  
  public String getFirstName()
  { 
    return firstName;
  }
  public String getLastName()
  { 
    return lastName;
  }
  
  public String getCountry()
  { 
    return country;
  }
  public int getRank()
  { 
    return rank;
  }
  public int getAge()
  { 
    return age;
  }
  
  public int getWins()
  { 
    return wins;
  }
  
  public int getLosses()
  { 
    return losses;
  }
 
   
  public double calcWinPercentage()
  {
     totalGames = wins +losses;
      if(totalGames != 0)
      {
      winningPercentage = (wins / totalGames);
      }else {
      winningPercentage = -1;}
 
      return winningPercentage;
  }
  
  public void displayPlayer()
  {   
      System.out.println("Tennis Player: " + firstName + "" + lastName);
      System.out.println("Country: " + country + "\n");
      System.out.println("Rank: " + rank + "\n");
      System.out.println("Age: " + age + "\n");
      System.out.println("Wins: " + wins);
      System.out.println("Losses: " + losses);
      System.out.println("Winning Percentage : " + winPercentage*100);
      System.out.println("----------------------------");
      System.out.println("----------------------------");
  }
}
```

```html
public class ShresthaTennisPlayer
{
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  
  private String country;
  
  private int rank;
  private int age;
  
  private int wins;
  private int losses;
  
  double winningPercentage;
  double totalGames;
  
  double winPercentage = calcWinPercentage();
  
  public ShresthaTennisPlayer()
  { 
      firstName = null;
      lastName = null;
      country = null;
      
      rank = 0;
      age = 0;
      wins = 0;
      losses = 0; 
  }
  
  public ShresthaTennisPlayer(String FName, String LName, String CountryName)
  {
  firstName = FName;
  lastName = LName;
  country = CountryName;
  
  rank = 0;
  age = 0;
  wins = 0;
  losses = 0;
  }
  
  
  public ShresthaTennisPlayer(String FName, String LName, String CountryName, int r, int a)
  {
  firstName = FName;
  lastName = LName;
  country = CountryName;
  
  rank = r;
  age = a;
  wins = 0;
  losses = 0;
  }
  
  public ShresthaTennisPlayer(String FName, String LName, String CountryName, int r, int a, int w, int l)
  {
  firstName = FName;
  lastName = LName;
  country = CountryName;
  
  rank = r;
  age = a;
  wins = w;
  losses = l;
  }
  public void setFirstName(String FName)
  {
    firstName = FName;
  }
  
  public void setLastName(String LName)
  {
lastName = LName;
  }
  
  public void setCountry(String CountryName)
  {
    country = CountryName;
  }
  
  public void setRank(int r)
  {
    rank = r;
  }
  
  public void setAge(int a)
  {
age = a;
  }
  
  public void setWins(int w)
  {
    wins = w;
  }
  
  public void setLosses(int l)
  {
    losses = l;
  }
  
  public String getFirstName()
  { 
    return firstName;
  }
  public String getLastName()
  { 
    return lastName;
  }
  
  public String getCountry()
  { 
    return country;
  }
  public int getRank()
  { 
    return rank;
  }
  public int getAge()
  { 
    return age;
  }
  
  public int getWins()
  { 
    return wins;
  }
  
  public int getLosses()
  { 
    return losses;
  }
 
   
  public double calcWinPercentage()
  {
     totalGames = wins +losses;
      if(totalGames != 0)
      {
      winningPercentage = (wins / totalGames);
      }else {
      winningPercentage = -1;}
 
      return winningPercentage;
  }
  
  public void displayPlayer()
  {   
      System.out.println("Tennis Player: " + firstName + "" + lastName);
      System.out.println("Country: " + country + "\n");
      System.out.println("Rank: " + rank + "\n");
      System.out.println("Age: " + age + "\n");
      System.out.println("Wins: " + wins);
      System.out.println("Losses: " + losses);
      System.out.println("Winning Percentage : " + winPercentage*100);
      System.out.println("----------------------------");
      System.out.println("----------------------------");
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC-BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted and subsequent attempts will get you banned. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/584192)?

Answer (score 0):

The line `double winPercentage = calcWinPercentage()` is executed before you call the constructor, thus your `wins` and `losses` variables are not set yet. Since you already have the `winningPercentage` variable, you could just call `calcWinPercentage()` at the end of your constructors to set `winningPercentage`, like:

```
  public ShresthaTennisPlayer(String FName, String LName, String CountryName, int r, int a)
  {
  firstName = FName;
  lastName = LName;
  country = CountryName;
  
  rank = r;
  age = a;
  wins = 0;
  losses = 0;

  calcWinPercentage();
  }
```

Then in your `displayPlayer()` method, change `winPercentage` to `winningPercentage`

Comment: Maybe add an if statement that checks the value of `winningPercentage` and prints different statements based on the value

Answer (score 0):

You gotten -100 coz in your calcWinPercentage(), it returns -1.
And then in displayPlayer(), you multiply by 100.

Try debugging in an IDE e.g. Intellij Community Edition or Eclipse.